# Converting PDF to PDF/A sufficient to disable javascript in file?

Tags: javascript, security, pdf, javascript-injection, pdfa

If I have a pdf file with malicious javascript embedded in it (visible or obfuscated) - will converting that file to pdf/a format (with a commercial tool) deactivate the javascript - making the file safe ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The intention of the PDF/A standard is clearly that no JavaScript/ECMAScript actions remain. While it might be possible to "hide" JavaScript in the PDF, any PDF/A converter should remove any JavaScript that might normally be executed.

So yes, PDF/A conversion should "deactivate" any JavaScript. Of course, you would need to review the actual PDF/A implementation used to make sure that is the case, but leaving anything dynamic in the PDF, like JavaScript, goes against the intentions of the ISO PDF/A specification.

Comment: Thank you! I see you are involved with PDFTron - I will put PDFTron at the top of the list  when reviewing proof of concepts for this task I have. I'm reviewing PDF/A conversion as a possible security remediation tactic for a specific company and workflow, and this information is helpful.